# File Generation & Handling in Smart Devices (Genexus)

Tags: ios, file, directory, device, genexus

I'm working on a Mobile Application in Genexus X Evolution 3 (iOS) which executes an External Object method (objective-c) made by me that gathers motion info. All this info generates a CSV file, which I want to grab with Genexus and send to an online server. My problem is I can't find the directory where the file is stored. I know Genexus creates a 'GXData' directory inside the 'Documents' directory to avoid the use of the same directory in which the offline databases are created, but I don't know how to access this directory from a procedure in Genexus, So please if anyone can lend me a hand on this I will be in your debt forever!

Best Regards!

Comment: What are you going to do with that file? Read it? Copy to somewhere else? Can you post some code of the things you tried?

Comment: Marcos, te escribo en español, tal como asumis trabajo con Walter. No tenemos codigo generado todavia. Lo que quiero es tomar ese archivo almacenado en el telefono en un blob y llevarmelo a un servidor online. El archivo puede generarse con o sin conexion y recien en el servidor se procesaria sin que el telefono tenga que intervenir.

Comment: El workflow es asi: la app en genexus llama un external object (objective-c), en objective-c accedemos al hardware (acelerometro y giroscopio). Capturamos datos (cada 10 milisegundos) y por hora obtenemos varios millones de registros, son muchos para procesar a la vez. POr eso generamos un CSV. a ese CSV quiero hacerle un boton "sync" que me haga un upload al servidor en donde genexus va a procesar el archivo por fuera de la app.

Comment: Lo que necesitamos es saber en donde buscar el archivo desde genexus. O sea, como obtengo el archivo generado (en el telefono en Documents/GxData) desde genexus? no sabemos cual es la ruta completa del archivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in iOS to know the application's installation directory during the development process.

That's why the `Directory` data type defines three static properties, to be used by the GeneXus developer. This properties are platform-independent, installation-independent, so you can use them safely.

The defined properties are:

- `ApplicationDataPath`: points to Documents/GXData/
- `ExternalFilesPath`: same as ApplicationDataPath on iOS, the external memory path for Android
- `TemporaryFilesPath`: the tmp/ folder for the application.

You could write for example

```
&file.Source = Directory.TemporaryFilesPath + &file.Separator + "myFile.txt"
```

where `&file` is defined to be of type `File`.

And then, you can read the content of the file with:

```
&fileContent = &file.ReadAllText()
```

Be warned that if the file is too big, it may cause memory or performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the static properties of the Directory data type in order to access the local directories of the device. Using these properties you can easily work with the file system of the device like any other GeneXus application.

If you want to learn more about these properties and many other considerations please refer to: http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?27388